# Arabic letters do not Connect together

Tags: image, encoding, arabic

I have a little problem when I am converting Arabic word to image, on the image words are connecting to each other, like : سعادة look like that : س ع ا د ة

What could the problem be?

Comment: What tool/library/functions are you using to convert the word to image? Sample code might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

The characters in the arabic language have a different look if they are alone (isolated form), at the beginning, middle or end of a word. So there is the internal charset specific key code which - i assume - maps to the single form, but the application is responsible to select the correct presentation form (another character) while rendering the GUI or your image. A typical application which does not understand arabic, displays the characters only by their code, which works for western languages but not for arabic.